# Find a formula that defines the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find a formula for the general term $a_n$ of the sequence
$$\left\{\frac35,-\frac{4}{25},\frac{5}{125},-\frac{6}{625},\frac{7}{3125},\dots \right\}$$
Answer: $a_n=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{n+2}{5^n}$

My attempt:

$a_1=\frac35=\frac{-(2+1)}{-5^1}$

$a_2=-\frac{4}{25}=\frac{(-1)^2(2+2)}{-5^2}$

$a_n=\frac{(2+n)(-1)^n}{-5^n}$

I think that my take gives a formula that defines the sequence, but since it's different from the given answer, I'm not sure.

Was my attempt successful?

Comment: Is your answer *really* different from the given answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula works. Notice it says name "a" formula. You could have just as well of raised -1 to (n+1),or n plus any odd natural number.